# existing pod is not qualifying by deployment object though i have same selector label

Tags: kubernetes

I just started learning kubernetes. Please help me out.

As per my assumption, when deplyoment object is going to create replica set based on the selector if any existing running pod with same label of selector used in deployment has to utilize by scheduler but in my below case it is not. Please correct me if am wrong, other wise please help me out where am going wrong.

```
pod.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
 name: web
 labels:
  type: frontend
spec:
 containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx

deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: web-deployment
spec:
 template:
  metadata: 
   name: web
   labels:
    type: frontend
  spec:
    containers:
     - name: nginx-container
       image: nginx
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   type: frontend
 replicas: 2
```

I have create a pod first then iam trying with deployment of same pod type.

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web                              1/1     Running   0          22m
web-deployment-89d6bf94f-5dqxj   1/1     Running   0          13m
web-deployment-89d6bf94f-xrngx   1/1     Running   0          21m
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at description of one of the pods(for example `kubectl describe pod web-deployment-89d6bf94f-5dqxj`), created by deployment, you will find that it has additional label `pod-template-hash`, that was added by deployment controller to it's underlying replica set. Here is little paragraph in [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template-hash-label) about how and why this label is set:

> This label ensures that child ReplicaSets of a Deployment do not overlap. It is generated by hashing the PodTemplate of the ReplicaSet and using the resulting hash as the label value that is added to the ReplicaSet selector, Pod template labels, and in any existing Pods that the ReplicaSet might have.

So, basically, pod that was created outside of deployment is not part of this deployment's replica set.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to override a pod specification via a deployment?

Why not just use the deployment?

If you want to edit a pod specification why not just edit it directly vs trying to override it with a deployment?

Comment: I am not trying to override pod, but wanted to utilized an existing POD with a new  deployment of same type of POD.